# Filter out files older than another file from a list in bash

Tags: bash

Given a list of file names, is there a way to remove the names from the list corresponding to files older than another file?

For example, if I have a string `"a b c"`, and file `a` is older than file `d`, but `b` and `c` are not, I want to turn the string into `"b c"`.

**Edit**, since people are asking for the specifics:

I want to reduce code duplication in this chunk of bash script:

```
for f in $(ls | grep '.json$'); do
  base=$(basename $f .json)
  regex=".*/${base}_[0-9]\{3\}-[0-9]\{3\}\.dat"
  if [ -z "$(find dat -regextype sed -regex ${regex})" ] || \
     [ -n "$(find dat -regextype sed -regex ${regex} -not -newer $f)" ] || \
     [ -n "$(find dat -regextype sed -regex ${regex} -not -newer ../bin/vars)" ]
  then
    echo $f
    ../bin/vars $f -o dat/$base \
      -b 200 250 300 350 400 450 500
  fi
done
```

Comment: You could use the find command... That has a -newer (-cnewer/-anewer/-newerXY) flag.

Comment: `for f in $(ls | grep '.json$')` (2 child processes) -> `for f in *.json` (0 child processes).

Comment: How many `*.json` files do you plan to have, approximately? Tens, hundreds, thousands? Am I correct to suppose that you don’t have any further subdirectory under `dat/` and that `dat/` contains only the `dat/${base}_[0-9]\{3\}-[0-9]\{3\}\.dat` files generated by each `${base}.json` file? How many of them are there? I suspect that the two sequences of three digits after `${base}` are pairs taken from `200 250 300 350 400 450 500`. According to which rule?

Comment: @Dario Thanks for trying, but this discussion would be off topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a comparison operator `-nt` ("newer than") to compare two files. If you have these files:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 benjamin staff   0 Jun 20 11:30 a.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 benjamin staff   0 Jun 20 11:34 b.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 benjamin staff   0 Jun 20 11:34 c.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 benjamin staff   0 Jun 20 11:32 d.json
```

then you can use it as follows:

```
$ for f in {a,b,c}.json; do [[ $f -nt d.json ]] && echo "$f"; done
b.json
c.json
```

Wrapped in a function that expects the reference file as the first argument and the list of filenames as the rest of the arguments:

```
filterfiles () {
    local filtered
    for f in "${@:1}"; do
        [[ $f -nt $1 ]] && filtered+=("$f")
    done
    echo "${filtered[@]}"
}
```

to be used like

```
$ filterfiles d.json {a,b,c}.json
b.json c.json
```

Alternatively, if you just want to know if at least one file is newer than the reference file (as alluded to in comments):

```
filterfiles () {
    for f in "${@:1}"; do
        [[ $f -nt $1 ]] && return 0
    done
    return 1
}
```

Now, you can check the return value of the function:

```
if filterfiles d.json {a,b,c}.json; then echo "Array contains newer file"; fi
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it more concisely? All I need for now, is to check whether at least one of the files is newer.

Comment: @SU3 I've added a second solution that just checks if any of the files in a given list are newer than a reference file.